# Filter XSLT ListView with metadats as tags

Tags: filter, xslt-list-view-web-part, metadata

**My goals**

A documents library has a Metadata column.

- In a webpart page,

  - user selects (through select2) several metadatas as tags.
  - the tag(s) (one or many) are sent to a XSLT ListView
  - XSLT ListView is supposed to be filtered with "contains" this tag1 OR this tag2 OR this tag3 etc.

What is the best way to achieve this goal?

(parameters and customization of the query through SPD are supposing fixed number of contains?)

Answer (score 0):

How about [Metadata Navigation and Filtering](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint-server-help/configure-metadata-navigation-for-a-list-or-library-HA101820113.aspx)?

Metadata navigation enables users to dynamically filter and find content in lists and libraries by using a navigation hierarchy tree control to apply different metadata-based filters to the view.

Example:

Assume a Document library contains managed metadata column named  `Document Type` and `Enterprise Keywords` column has been added into Library.

Then you could construct a comprehensive filters as demonstrated below

[image]

Filter documents by `Order` Document Type and include only documents tagged with `Public` keyword

Comment: Tk Vadim. I know this OOB solution. Unfortunately, I wanted to customize it, OR to rebuild one : I need more space than the one provided in the navigation pane. And, I wanted to use select2 search button to give more information (their will be a lot of différents tags able to be choosen).